# CSS Flexbox navigation and margin

Tags: html, css, flexbox, nav

Simple nav based on a list with `display: flex` applied. The first element shifted to the left side but for some reason, I get a `"space"` on the right side.

I can't find out if that's a `margin` or a `padding` and which element causes it. Code inspector in Chrome suggests it might be a `ul` `margin-block-start` but, I don't understand where it comes from and doesn't know how to get rid of it.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
    font-size: 18px;
}

html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {

    text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    color: #363636;
    font-size: 1em;
    overflow-x: hidden
        /*Chrome*/
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    border: dotted green;
    background-color: #eb1734;
    padding: 2rem;
    z-index:99;
}

nav>ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    border: dotted yellow;
    margin: 0
}

nav>ul>li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.logo {
    margin-right: auto;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}



.wrapper {
    padding: 0 1rem;
}


.hero {

    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    max-width: 100%;
    /*to prevent the horizontal overflow*/
    background-color: #eb1734;
    color: #f6f6f6;
    display: table;
    /* and let the ancient aliens centre */

}

.hero h2 {
    margin: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.6rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.subtitle {

    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: italic;
}

.txt_sm {
    font-size: 0.98rem;
}

.txt_tm {
    font-size: 0.72rem;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 1.8rem
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.6rem
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.1rem
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.arrow {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1em;
    left: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1em;
}

.arrow,
.arrow:visited {
    color: #f6f6f6;
}

.panel {
    border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    background: #f6f7f8;
}

#welcome {
    text-align: center;
    color: #eb1734;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding: 4rem 0 3rem;
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25/1),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
only screen and (min-resolution: 200dpi),
only screen and (min-resolution: 1.25dppx) {}


@media (min-width: 1281px) {

    .wrapper {
        padding: 0 9rem;
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width:1000px) {
    .grid {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;

    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width:800px) {
    .grid {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
}
```

```html
   <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="logo"><a href="#">Section 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Section 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Section 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Section 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Section 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <section class="hero">
            <h2><span class="title">Praesent elementum feugiat.</span><br>
                <span class="subtitle txt_sm">Suspendisse rhoncus sodales odio vel ultrices.</span>
            </h2>
            <a class="arrow" href="#welcome">&darr;</a>
        </section>
    </header>
    <div class="wrapper home">
        <section id="welcome">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eget sem in orci cursus congue. Morbi
                pulvinar augue sed elementum iaculis.</p>
        </section>
        <section id="about">
            <h2>Pellentesque viverra sapien</h2>
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eget sem in orci cursus congue. Morbi
                pulvinar augue sed elementum iaculis. Pellentesque viverra sapien vitae ligula lacinia, tincidunt
                vehicula ante mattis. Donec in mauris a libero gravida placerat a at ipsum. Curabitur eu varius odio.
                Sed vitae ultricies enim. Curabitur at fringilla urna, ac blandit eros. Maecenas ut semper quam.
                Suspendisse congue interdum ipsum non elementum. Aenean congue nulla a quam convallis, quis facilisis
                turpis pellentesque. Nulla eros lectus, egestas lacinia risus at, bibendum rhoncus nisi. Maecenas eget
                dignissim urna. Suspendisse rhoncus sodales odio vel ultrices.</p>
            <p>
                Praesent elementum feugiat tincidunt. Phasellus pharetra est urna, fringilla venenatis velit iaculis
                nec. Nullam cursus laoreet tempor. Vivamus mollis velit id ultrices pulvinar. Vestibulum dapibus
                hendrerit malesuada. Nulla facilisi. Morbi sed nulla faucibus, interdum arcu sit amet, rhoncus sem.
                Nunc nec quam elit. Nunc ultrices, odio vitae rutrum porta, velit eros sollicitudin leo, non tempus
                felis mi sit amet odio. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
                inceptos himenaeos. Sed at gravida tellus, quis imperdiet metus. Cras vehicula tristique egestas. </p>
        </section>
        <h2>Vivamus mollis</h2>
        <section class="grid">

            <section>
                <h3>1</h3>
                <p>Praesent elementum feugiat tincidunt. Phasellus pharetra est urna, fringilla venenatis velit iaculis
                    nec. Nullam cursus laoreet tempor. Vivamus mollis velit id ultrices pulvinar. Vestibulum dapibus
                    hendrerit malesuada. Nulla facilisi. Morbi sed nulla faucibus, interdum arcu sit amet, rhoncus sem.
                    Nunc nec quam elit.</p>
            </section>
            <section>
                <h3>2</h3>
                <p>Praesent elementum feugiat tincidunt. Phasellus pharetra est urna, fringilla venenatis velit iaculis
                    nec. Nullam cursus laoreet tempor. Vivamus mollis velit id ultrices pulvinar. Vestibulum dapibus
                    hendrerit malesuada. Nulla facilisi. Morbi sed nulla faucibus, interdum arcu sit amet, rhoncus sem.
                    Nunc nec quam elit.</p>
            </section>
            <section>
                <h3>3</h3>
                <p>Praesent elementum feugiat tincidunt. Phasellus pharetra est urna, fringilla venenatis velit iaculis
                    nec. Nullam cursus laoreet tempor. Vivamus mollis velit id ultrices pulvinar. Vestibulum dapibus
                    hendrerit malesuada. Nulla facilisi. Morbi sed nulla faucibus, interdum arcu sit amet, rhoncus sem.
                    Nunc nec quam elit.</p>
            </section>
            <section>
                <h3>4</h3>
                <p>Praesent elementum feugiat tincidunt. Phasellus pharetra est urna, fringilla venenatis velit iaculis
                    nec. Nullam cursus laoreet tempor. Vivamus mollis velit id ultrices pulvinar. Vestibulum dapibus
                    hendrerit malesuada. Nulla facilisi. Morbi sed nulla faucibus, interdum arcu sit amet, rhoncus sem.
                    Nunc nec quam elit.</p>
            </section>
            <section>
                <h3>5</h3>
                <p>Praesent elementum feugiat tincidunt. Phasellus pharetra est urna, fringilla venenatis velit iaculis
                    nec. Nullam cursus laoreet tempor. Vivamus mollis velit id ultrices pulvinar. Vestibulum dapibus
                    hendrerit malesuada. Nulla facilisi. Morbi sed nulla faucibus, interdum arcu sit amet, rhoncus sem.
                    Nunc nec quam elit.</p>
            </section>
            <section>
                <h3>6</h3>
                <p>Praesent elementum feugiat tincidunt. Phasellus pharetra est urna, fringilla venenatis velit iaculis
                    nec. Nullam cursus laoreet tempor. Vivamus mollis velit id ultrices pulvinar. Vestibulum dapibus
                    hendrerit malesuada. Nulla facilisi. Morbi sed nulla faucibus, interdum arcu sit amet, rhoncus sem.
                    Nunc nec quam elit.</p>
            </section>
        </section>
    </div>
    <!--wrapper END-->
    <section class="panel">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h3>Panel</h3>
            <p>Praesent elementum feugiat tincidunt. Phasellus pharetra est urna, fringilla venenatis velit iaculis
                nec. Nullam cursus laoreet tempor. Vivamus mollis velit id ultrices pulvinar. Vestibulum dapibus
                hendrerit malesuada. Nulla facilisi. Morbi sed nulla faucibus, interdum arcu sit amet, rhoncus sem.
                Nunc nec quam elit.</p>
        </div>
        <!--wrapper END-->
    </section>
    <footer class="wrapper">
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eget sem in orci cursus congue. Morbi
            pulvinar augue sed elementum iaculis. Pellentesque viverra sapien vitae ligula lacinia, tincidunt
            vehicula ante mattis. Donec in mauris a libero gravida placerat a at ipsum. Curabitur eu varius odio.
            Sed vitae ultricies enim. Curabitur at fringilla urna, ac blandit eros. Maecenas ut semper quam.
            Suspendisse congue interdum ipsum non elementum. Aenean congue nulla a quam convallis, quis facilisis
            turpis pellentesque. Nulla eros lectus, egestas lacinia risus at, bibendum rhoncus nisi. Maecenas eget
            dignissim urna. Suspendisse rhoncus sodales odio vel ultrices.</p>
    </footer>
```

Comment: I don't see any space on the right side of the nav element that doesn't exist on the left side so I'm confused.

Comment: do you mean left?

Comment: I meant left, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

set `padding:0` to UL it is browser's default css style you need to override that by setting `padding:0` to UL

Comment: I guess I was looking at the code too long. <ul> padding it the obvious reason but I'm not sure why it's only on the left side.

Comment: The problem is that by default, browsers have custom css - in chrome for example: ul{ -webkit-padding-start: 40px;}

Answer (score 0):

The first `li` element has a `logo` class.

removing this (or the class) fixes your problem (if I understand you right)

```
.logo {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Next time read the guidelines to post question, your code is not a minimal example to reproduce the problem, and be more specific, name which element, you can put a picture, anything. I'm assuming you are talking about that first li item, but you can be clearer when you ask.

Answer (score 0):

`ul` elements have a default padding which causes your problem. If you add `padding: 0` to `nav>ul`, the first flex item (i.e. the future logo) will be aligned left - I suppose that's what you want(?).

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
    font-size: 18px;
}

html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {

    text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    color: #363636;
    font-size: 1em;
    overflow-x: hidden
        /*Chrome*/
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    border: dotted green;
    background-color: #eb1734;
    padding: 2rem;
    z-index:99;
}

nav>ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    border: dotted yellow;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav>ul>li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.logo {
    margin-right: auto;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}



.wrapper {
    padding: 0 1rem;
}


.hero {

    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    max-width: 100%;
    /*to prevent the horizontal overflow*/
    background-color: #eb1734;
    color: #f6f6f6;
    display: table;
    /* and let the ancient aliens centre */

}

.hero h2 {
    margin: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.6rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.subtitle {

    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: italic;
}

.txt_sm {
    font-size: 0.98rem;
}

.txt_tm {
    font-size: 0.72rem;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 1.8rem
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.6rem
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.1rem
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.arrow {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1em;
    left: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1em;
}

.arrow,
.arrow:visited {
    color: #f6f6f6;
}

.panel {
    border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    background: #f6f7f8;
}

#welcome {
    text-align: center;
    color: #eb1734;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding: 4rem 0 3rem;
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25/1),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
only screen and (min-resolution: 200dpi),
only screen and (min-resolution: 1.25dppx) {}


@media (min-width: 1281px) {

    .wrapper {
        padding: 0 9rem;
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width:1000px) {
    .grid {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;

    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width:800px) {
    .grid {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="logo"><a href="#">Section 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Section 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Section 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Section 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Section 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <section class="hero">
            <h2><span class="title">Praesent elementum feugiat.</span><br>
                <span class="subtitle txt_sm">Suspendisse rhoncus sodales odio vel ultrices.</span>
            </h2>
            <a class="arrow" href="#welcome">&darr;</a>
        </section>
    </header>
    <div class="wrapper home">
        <section id="welcome">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eget sem in orci cursus congue. Morbi
                pulvinar augue sed elementum iaculis.</p>
        </section>
        <section id="about">
            <h2>Pellentesque viverra sapien</h2>
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eget sem in orci cursus congue. Morbi
                pulvinar augue sed elementum iaculis. Pellentesque viverra sapien vitae ligula lacinia, tincidunt
                vehicula ante mattis. Donec in mauris a libero gravida placerat a at ipsum. Curabitur eu varius odio.
                Sed vitae ultricies enim. Curabitur at fringilla urna, ac blandit eros. Maecenas ut semper quam.
                Suspendisse congue interdum ipsum non elementum. Aenean congue nulla a quam convallis, quis facilisis
                turpis pellentesque. Nulla eros lectus, egestas lacinia risus at, bibendum rhoncus nisi. Maecenas eget
                dignissim urna. Suspendisse rhoncus sodales odio vel ultrices.</p>
            <p>
                Praesent elementum feugiat tincidunt. Phasellus pharetra est urna, fringilla venenatis velit iaculis
                nec. Nullam cursus laoreet tempor. Vivamus mollis velit id ultrices pulvinar. Vestibulum dapibus
                hendrerit malesuada. Nulla facilisi. Morbi sed nulla faucibus, interdum arcu sit amet, rhoncus sem.
                Nunc nec quam elit. Nunc ultrices, odio vitae rutrum porta, velit eros sollicitudin leo, non tempus
                felis mi sit amet odio. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
                inceptos himenaeos. Sed at gravida tellus, quis imperdiet metus. Cras vehicula tristique egestas. </p>
        </section>
        <h2>Vivamus mollis</h2>
        <section class="grid">

            <section>
                <h3>1</h3>
                <p>Praesent elementum feugiat tincidunt. Phasellus pharetra est urna, fringilla venenatis velit iaculis
                    nec. Nullam cursus laoreet tempor. Vivamus mollis velit id ultrices pulvinar. Vestibulum dapibus
                    hendrerit malesuada. Nulla facilisi. Morbi sed nulla faucibus, interdum arcu sit amet, rhoncus sem.
                    Nunc nec quam elit.</p>
            </section>
            <section>
                <h3>2</h3>
                <p>Praesent elementum feugiat tincidunt. Phasellus pharetra est urna, fringilla venenatis velit iaculis
                    nec. Nullam cursus laoreet tempor. Vivamus mollis velit id ultrices pulvinar. Vestibulum dapibus
                    hendrerit malesuada. Nulla facilisi. Morbi sed nulla faucibus, interdum arcu sit amet, rhoncus sem.
                    Nunc nec quam elit.</p>
            </section>
            <section>
                <h3>3</h3>
                <p>Praesent elementum feugiat tincidunt. Phasellus pharetra est urna, fringilla venenatis velit iaculis
                    nec. Nullam cursus laoreet tempor. Vivamus mollis velit id ultrices pulvinar. Vestibulum dapibus
                    hendrerit malesuada. Nulla facilisi. Morbi sed nulla faucibus, interdum arcu sit amet, rhoncus sem.
                    Nunc nec quam elit.</p>
            </section>
            <section>
                <h3>4</h3>
                <p>Praesent elementum feugiat tincidunt. Phasellus pharetra est urna, fringilla venenatis velit iaculis
                    nec. Nullam cursus laoreet tempor. Vivamus mollis velit id ultrices pulvinar. Vestibulum dapibus
                    hendrerit malesuada. Nulla facilisi. Morbi sed nulla faucibus, interdum arcu sit amet, rhoncus sem.
                    Nunc nec quam elit.</p>
            </section>
            <section>
                <h3>5</h3>
                <p>Praesent elementum feugiat tincidunt. Phasellus pharetra est urna, fringilla venenatis velit iaculis
                    nec. Nullam cursus laoreet tempor. Vivamus mollis velit id ultrices pulvinar. Vestibulum dapibus
                    hendrerit malesuada. Nulla facilisi. Morbi sed nulla faucibus, interdum arcu sit amet, rhoncus sem.
                    Nunc nec quam elit.</p>
            </section>
            <section>
                <h3>6</h3>
                <p>Praesent elementum feugiat tincidunt. Phasellus pharetra est urna, fringilla venenatis velit iaculis
                    nec. Nullam cursus laoreet tempor. Vivamus mollis velit id ultrices pulvinar. Vestibulum dapibus
                    hendrerit malesuada. Nulla facilisi. Morbi sed nulla faucibus, interdum arcu sit amet, rhoncus sem.
                    Nunc nec quam elit.</p>
            </section>
        </section>
    </div>
    <!--wrapper END-->
    <section class="panel">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h3>Panel</h3>
            <p>Praesent elementum feugiat tincidunt. Phasellus pharetra est urna, fringilla venenatis velit iaculis
                nec. Nullam cursus laoreet tempor. Vivamus mollis velit id ultrices pulvinar. Vestibulum dapibus
                hendrerit malesuada. Nulla facilisi. Morbi sed nulla faucibus, interdum arcu sit amet, rhoncus sem.
                Nunc nec quam elit.</p>
        </div>
        <!--wrapper END-->
    </section>
    <footer class="wrapper">
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eget sem in orci cursus congue. Morbi
            pulvinar augue sed elementum iaculis. Pellentesque viverra sapien vitae ligula lacinia, tincidunt
            vehicula ante mattis. Donec in mauris a libero gravida placerat a at ipsum. Curabitur eu varius odio.
            Sed vitae ultricies enim. Curabitur at fringilla urna, ac blandit eros. Maecenas ut semper quam.
            Suspendisse congue interdum ipsum non elementum. Aenean congue nulla a quam convallis, quis facilisis
            turpis pellentesque. Nulla eros lectus, egestas lacinia risus at, bibendum rhoncus nisi. Maecenas eget
            dignissim urna. Suspendisse rhoncus sodales odio vel ultrices.</p>
    </footer>
```